# PuTTy/KiTTy Killed by Global VPN Client, Cannot Reconnect

Tags: ssh, vpn, putty, sonicwall

Running PuTTy/KiTTy on a W10 machine, I connect to a work VPN (Global VPN Client). Connect fine, but connection is killed due to (I suspect) inactivity. That's fine. Sys admin has recommended to use the following: keepalives turned off (set to 0), using Auto for IPv, and check "Attempt to reconnect on connection failure". I have now set this up. I've attempted various setups, prior, covering just about everything client side, but the issue persists.

When I connect, the SSH connection works initially. Connects, but then drops due to inactivity. The SSH window becomes unresponsive and I have to close. Try to open the connection again though and I can not connect whatsoever (does not display anything in the SSH window) and I get a "Network error: Connection timed out". Only thing that works is if I restart the VPN client software (Global VPN), which brings me back to square one and the issue repeats.

Believe this is a problem with the client side software / server side firewall settings. I can connect via VPN using Windows VPN and do not experience this issue (to what I'm led to believe is the same connection). However, this also creates another issue for me using the Windows VPN issue.

If anyone has a couple of pointers I can give my sysadmin to help resolve this issue would be amazing.

Comment: "Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 120"

Add this to server side sshd config file.

Comment: You should check between two disconnects if you appear as coming from the same address or a different address (eg: `who` on the target server). Maybe the disconnect happens at the VPN part rather than at the specific TCP flow.

Comment: We've ran this by the sys admin, everything is appearing correctly. It appears this is an issue with my ISP, as we've replicated the issue on other equipment on the same connection. However, it works on different connections.

Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is an issue related to my ISP, or their equipment. We have replicated the issue on other devices from this connection, however it does not effect devices using a different connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can change putty settings like this: [image: putty keep alive settings]

On server side add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60

ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Comment: Have tried. This does not work. Same issue presents itself.

Comment: Can you lover  it to 60sec?? And did you changed server sshd configuration?

Comment: I have tried 60sec. I've tried 30 sec. But I don't have access to the server side sshd config. Will have to run it by the sys admin when they return

Comment: In case you solve problem, it would be nice if you share it here, so others can make use of it.

Comment: Absolutely. I will enquire once they return and update what's happening.

Comment: So, I did run this stuff by the server admin. Didn't work, as apparently it's already set up correctly on their end (RE: your suggestion). 

We have tried the connection from other locations, and it works. So, it has to be an issue with my ISP, or their equipment. Have replicated the issue on other equipment from the same location / connection.

Thank you for your help.